# Polymorphic implementation for == with CRTP

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading

I'm trying to implement equality for all types that share same base.

Consider `std::vector<unique_ptr<Shape>>` and that we want to check if a certain given `Shape&` is *equal* to a certain shape managed in the vector. The idea is to have a generic solution through a base class, without relying on the exact content of the derived classes and without narrowing it to shapes (which is merely just a usage example).

I came to the following solution, with [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and would appreciate comments.

[Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17f786455c192ab9)

### AbstractBase

```
class AbstractBase {
    virtual bool base_equals(const AbstractBase& other) const = 0;
    virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream& out = std::cout) const = 0;
public:
    bool operator==(const AbstractBase& other)const {
        if(typeid(*this)==typeid(other)) {
            return this->base_equals(other);
        }
        return false;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const AbstractBase& ab) {
        out << "[" << (void*)&ab << "] ";
        return ab.print(out);
    }
};
```

### CRTP Base

```
template<class ActualType>
class Base: public AbstractBase {
    virtual bool base_equals(const AbstractBase& other)const override final {
        return static_cast<const ActualType&>(*this)
                    == static_cast<const ActualType&>(other);
    }
};
```

### Actual Classes

```
class A: public Base<A> {
    int num;
    virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream& out = std::cout) const {
        return out << num;
    }
public:
    A(int i = 42): num(i) {}
    bool operator==(const A& a)const {
        return num == a.num;
    }
};

class B: public Base<B> {
    std::string str;
    virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream& out = std::cout) const {
        return out << str;
    }
public:
    B(const std::string& s = "hello"): str(s) {}
    bool operator==(const B& b)const {
        return str == b.str;
    }
};
```

### Simple Usage Example *(Test)*

```
int main() {
    A a1, a2, a3 = 5;
    B b1, b2, b3 = {"bye"};
    std::vector<const AbstractBase*> arr = {&a1, &a2, &a3, &b1, &b2, &b3};
    for(auto v1: arr) {
        for(auto v2: arr) {
            std::cout << *v1 << " == " << *v2 << " ? "
                      << std::boolalpha << (*v1 == *v2) << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
[0x7ffefdb7f0b0] 42     ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0b0] 42     ?   true
[0x7ffefdb7f0b0] 42     ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0c0] 42     ?   true
[0x7ffefdb7f0b0] 42     ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0d0] 5      ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f0b0] 42     ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0e0] hello  ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f0b0] 42     ==  [0x7ffefdb7f110] hello  ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f0b0] 42     ==  [0x7ffefdb7f140] bye    ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f0c0] 42     ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0b0] 42     ?   true
[0x7ffefdb7f0c0] 42     ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0c0] 42     ?   true
[0x7ffefdb7f0c0] 42     ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0d0] 5      ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f0c0] 42     ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0e0] hello  ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f0c0] 42     ==  [0x7ffefdb7f110] hello  ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f0c0] 42     ==  [0x7ffefdb7f140] bye    ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f0d0] 5      ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0b0] 42     ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f0d0] 5      ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0c0] 42     ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f0d0] 5      ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0d0] 5      ?   true
[0x7ffefdb7f0d0] 5      ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0e0] hello  ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f0d0] 5      ==  [0x7ffefdb7f110] hello  ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f0d0] 5      ==  [0x7ffefdb7f140] bye    ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f0e0] hello  ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0b0] 42     ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f0e0] hello  ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0c0] 42     ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f0e0] hello  ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0d0] 5      ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f0e0] hello  ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0e0] hello  ?   true
[0x7ffefdb7f0e0] hello  ==  [0x7ffefdb7f110] hello  ?   true
[0x7ffefdb7f0e0] hello  ==  [0x7ffefdb7f140] bye    ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f110] hello  ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0b0] 42     ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f110] hello  ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0c0] 42     ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f110] hello  ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0d0] 5      ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f110] hello  ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0e0] hello  ?   true
[0x7ffefdb7f110] hello  ==  [0x7ffefdb7f110] hello  ?   true
[0x7ffefdb7f110] hello  ==  [0x7ffefdb7f140] bye    ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f140] bye    ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0b0] 42     ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f140] bye    ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0c0] 42     ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f140] bye    ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0d0] 5      ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f140] bye    ==  [0x7ffefdb7f0e0] hello  ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f140] bye    ==  [0x7ffefdb7f110] hello  ?   false
[0x7ffefdb7f140] bye    ==  [0x7ffefdb7f140] bye    ?   true
```

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. After getting an answer you are not allowed to change your code anymore. This is to ensure that answers do not get invalidated and have to hit a moving target. If you have changed your code you can either post it as an answer (if it would constitute a code review) or ask a new question with your changed code (linking back to this one as reference). Refer to [this post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/120114) for more information

Comment: The change comes with an "Edit" note that makes sure the reader follows + gives credit to the answer.

Comment: On hold as off topic?  Not an intuitive use case??  -- Consider `std::vector<unique_ptr<Shape>>` and we want to check if a certain given `Shape&` is equal to a certain shape managed in the vector.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9058/52915).

Comment: "Edit" notes still violate [site policy](/help/someone-answers). This is Code Review, not Collaborative Coding.

Comment: @AmirKirsh: you scenario (finding a shape in a vector of shapes) still has no defined meaning. In a polymorphic context, you would expect a `Rectangle` with equal sides to be equal to a `Square` of the same size, but your code would differentiate them. Inheritance is meaningful only in a context when you don't have to care / to know if you're dealing with the base or the derived class (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). 1/2

Comment: @AmirKirsh Moreover, in this case, you know the type you're looking for beforehand, so using CRTP to keep track of it is useless. For instance: `std::find_if(first, last, [&shape_to_find](const Shape& s) { using T = std::decay_t<decltype(shape_to_find)>; compatible_type_ptr = dynamic_cast<T*>(&s); if (ptr && *ptr == shape_to_find) return true; return false; });` (2/2)

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, I believe that your fundamental concept is flawed. Equality has a well defined meaning between objects of the same type, or between types themselves, but not in this hybrid scenario. For instance, let's say I have a `class C`, which inherits from `A` as well as from `Base<C>`, how shall I compare an instance of `A` and an instance of `C`? You would normally expect them to be comparable in a polymorphic context, at least if `A` implements `operator==`, wouldn't you? But their `type_info` is different. You could try and work around that problem by using `dynamic_cast`, but then I suspect that, given `A a; C c;`, `a == c` and `c == a` wouldn't return the same result, which is unexpected.

I suspect it's a kind of work-around you devised because you had a lot of vaguely related objects bunched together and realized afterwards you had to discriminate between them according to their concrete type.

But it would be best to improve on your overall design (that you can submit here, by the way), rather than persisting in the original one. Because what's the limit? Why not ordering objects of different types when you're at it? A common task when you have equality-comparable objects is to remove duplicates: you'll need to sort the objects to do it efficiently, meaning you have to implement `operator<` as well.

If you stick to your concept, though:

- Your base class lacks a virtual destructor. Any base class that will be used as a polymorphic handle needs a virtual destructor, or it might lead to resources leak (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)).
- The virtual `print` function clearly isn't in the right place (there's no conceptual link between equality and printability), but I suspect it's there only for the purpose of debugging.
- The code seems to be over-engineered. The only thing your CRTP base class does is a static down-cast, which could be a nice (static polymorphism) if the `base_equals` method wasn't called after already having performed run-time type identification. It's simpler to directly `dynamic_cast` your pointers.

For instance:

```
class Base {
    public:
    virtual bool operator==(const Base&) =0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

template <typename T>
class CRTP : public Base{
    virtual bool operator==(const Base& o) const override final {
        auto same_type = dynamic_cast<const T*>(&o);
        return same_type && static_cast<const T&>(*this) == *same_type;
    }
};
```

- there's a balance issue in your code, because it will accept to compare objects of different derived types not implementing the equality operator, but will refuse to compare objects of the same type if it doesn't implement it. To remedy that issue you can check through SFINAE or concepts (C++20) if equality comparison is implemented. Or you can make a different trade-off and skip the CRTP step:

For instance:

```
class Base {
    public:
    virtual bool operator==(const Base& o) const { return this == &o; }
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class A : public Base {
    public:
    int i = 4;
    virtual bool operator==(const Base& o) const override final {
        auto same_type = dynamic_cast<const A*>(&o);
        return same_type && i == same_type->i;
    }
};

class B : public Base {};
```

The downside is that you have to implement the down-casting in each derived base class, and the upside that you have a more consistent fall-back scenario for derived classes not implementing an equality operator.

Comment: missing virtual dtor - oops - taken ;

checking same_type with dynamic_cast is wrong it allows equality check between Person and Student on Person's fields -- the check with type_id is the correct way;

print - it is of course for the sake of the question and not to present any specific design coupling;

virtual operator== would take you to the derived class so you need to implement the "same_type" check in all derived classes... seems better to have non-virtual operator==;

Answer (score -2):

I apologize if I'm misunderstanding the problem your solving. If you're merely trying to first determine if two types are subclasses of a third, would it be possible to use avoid mixing an abstract base class and CRTP in favor of an operator overload like this? If so, you can get rid of the CRTP and the AbstractBase::base_equals method.

```
template< typename T, typename U >
bool operator==(T&& lhs, U&& rhs) { 
  return std::addressof(std::forward< T >(lhs)) == std::addressof(std::forward< U >(rhs)) ||
         std::is_base_of< AbstractBase, T >::value && std::is_base_of< AbstractBase, U >::value;
}
```

**In Response to Original Poster's Reply**

My earlier suggestion was simply (but not clearly stated) that you might pick either dynamic polymorphism or parametric polymorphism (not both). Also, I'm checking the memory addresses of objects to as a simple check of equality (to answer part of your reply).

Below is a solution I would use (using CRTP due to the different return types of getValue(); you could use dynamic polymorphism and achieve the same using operator<<). The hiccup is that you can no longer use std::vector, since you have pointers to both `BaseTemplate<A>*` and `BaseTemplate<B>*`, so you would need a heterogenous container in your driver code (ie std::tuple or the like).

Per the requirements in your reply, type/memory/value equality are checked with the free overloaded equality operators (you may need to decay the types if const/volatile cause types that fit your definition of equality don't bind to the correct operator== overload).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Derived> class BaseTemplate {
  std::ostream &print(std::ostream &out) const {
    return static_cast<const Derived *>(this)->print(out);
  }

public:
  const auto &getValue() const {
    return static_cast<const Derived *>(this)->getValue();
  }
  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out,
                                  const BaseTemplate<Derived> &rhs) {
    return out << "[" << (void *)&rhs << "] " << rhs.getValue();
  }
  auto operator*() const { return *static_cast<const Derived *>(this); }
};

class A : public BaseTemplate<A> {
  int num;

public:
  A(int i = 42) : num(i) {}
  const int &getValue() const { return num; }
  bool operator==(const A &a) const { return num == a.num; }
};

class B : public BaseTemplate<B> {
  std::string str;

public:
  B(const std::string &s = "hello") : str(s) {}
  const std::string &getValue() const { return str; }
  bool operator==(const B &b) const { return str == b.str; }
};

template <typename T, typename U> bool operator==(const T &lhs, const U &rhs) {
  return false;
}

template <typename T> bool operator==(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) {
  return std::addressof(lhs) == std::addressof(rhs) || lhs == rhs;
}
```

Comment: there are two needs: (a) to check that the type is identical; (b) to check that the value is equal. Note that the required equality is for value and not for address. @Kedar - your proposed code does (a) but doesn't do (b). The CRTP in my original code is for (b). How would you do (b)? Do you have a version without CRTP?

Comment: Might be that you have an infinite recursion in your new solution? Operator == calling itself.

Comment: It didn’t happen when I tested it, but to be sure, you can change the lhs == rhs (within the method) to lhs.getValue() == rhs.getValue()

Comment: Interesting that it didn't recurse for you. Did you test it by actually running the code? Can you share a link to the code? And for the alternative of calling getValue() does it mean that any type has this method? Does it mean that your solution is mainly for types with single value that implements the method getValue?

Comment: I did run the code. Your point is valid; I should do the value comparison with (lhs|rhs).getValue(); it’s safer and is part of your requirement anyway. All parameter types of BaseTemplate should have getValue(), though the code above actually doesn’t enforce it properly (since I overloaded operator*, which yields a const reference to an instance of BaseTemplate parameter type). If by your question about whether the solution is for single types, it’s for determining if types are the same, and if so, if they hold the same value). Non-matching types hit the other overload (which yields false).

Comment: The code is from above. I adapted the driver code to test type comparisons. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cf6f3a7addbe271

Comment: your code never goes to `template <typename T> bool operator==(const T &lhs, const T &rhs)` so it's not clear how it is supposed to be used. Still, if it would go there - it will be an infinite recursion.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I corrected it in the following link; I removed the overloads from within the classes (so equality is handled generically): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e295fcd5cc27bb5